# Output unformatted C++ similar to FORTRAN

Tags: c++, fortran, output, ofstream

I'm looking to convert some FORTRAN code to C++. 
I'm having some issues around the unformatted outputs.

In FORTRAN I have some code as follows

```
program main
integer*4 :: one
one = 1
open(unit = temp, file = "temp.dat", status = 'replace', form='unformatted')
WRITE(temp) one, one
end
```

The output of this code ends up being

```
0x0800 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000 0800 0000 
0x0a
```

So to me it appears as if the output is a little bit strange. I've been playing around with it, and I think the 0x08 is for a size of the variables being written, the two 0x00000001 are for the two four byte ones being written and the 0x00000008 may be a closing size buffer (I don't know why this would be 4 bytes when the opening buffer is a single byte). The 0x00000a appears to be an EOF character.

When I try to mimic the output with C++, I do

```
int main(){
    long one = 1;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("temp.dat", std::ofstream::out)
    outFile << one << one;
    outFile.close()
}
```

This didn't work because it tried to write the string for 1 out instead of the binary, so then I tried:

```
int main(){
    long one = 1;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("temp.dat", std::ofstream::out) 
    outFile.write((char*) one, sizeof(one));  //Line a
    outFile.write((char*) one, sizeof(one));
    outFile.close()
}
```

In hopes that by casting it as a char, the direct binary would be output. 
Unfortunately this has a SigSev fault on line a. I'm not quite sure why.

Is an approach like this a good approach, or should I try to go in a different direction?

Comment: Make sure to [open](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) the file in [binary mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode).

Comment: FORTRAN writes the size of the record before and after each write.  So your guess was correct.

Comment: Try `outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&one), sizeof one);`

Comment: Output like this from a Fortran program is not interchangeable: how such data are written may vary by compiler and by compiler version, or even by properties of the record to be written.  Depending on what you want to do with the output you may be better not trying to mimic what your Fortran compiler is doing.

Answer (score 1):

So stealing from chtz, I found a way to match the two outputs. I don't know if this is the most efficient.

```
int main(){
    int one = 1;
    int sizeOf = 2*sizeof(one);
    std::ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("temp.dat", std::ofstream::out) 
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sizeOf),sizeof(sizeOf)); 
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&one),sizeof(one));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&one),sizeof(one));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&sizeOf),sizeof(sizeOf));  

    outFile.close()
}
```